# How to duplicate a table entry and its dependency table rows mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I need to duplicate data in a table using MySQL, but this data has a one-to-many relationship with other tables.

TABLE A [1]---------[N] TABLE B [1]---------[N] TABLE C

So what I need to do is duplicate an entry from table one and to the same with its related data in the other tables.

I'm able to do this if this was a one-to-one relationship but I really don't know how to do it in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
INSERT INTO TABLE A1 (COL1, COL2, COL3)
SELECT * FROM TABLE A
[WHERE CONDITION]

INSERT INTO TABLE B1 (COL1, COL2, COL3)
SELECT B.COL1, B.COL2, B.COL3
    FROM TABLEB AS B
    INNER JOIN TABLEA
    ON [RELATIONSHIP]
    [WHERE CONDITION] --SAME AS THE FIRST

   INSERT INTO TABLE C1 (COL1,  COL2, cOL3)
   SELECT C.COL1,  C.COL2, C.COL3
       FROM TABLEC AS C
       INNER JOIN TABLEB
       ON [RELATIONSHIP C=B]
       INNER JOIN TABLEA
       ON [RELATIONSHIP B=A]
       [WHERE CONDITION] --SAME AS THE FIRST
```

Edit:  You can specify values for autoincrement according to this: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,167702,167717#msg-167717

Comment: hi Kafuka, thanks for the reply. this works great when i duplicate the data from table A and B, but how do i get it to duplicate the data from table C? how must the 3rd insert statement be in order to duplicate the data from table C that is related to table B?

Comment: i created a small db with 3 tables to simplify this test and i get the following error: 'cannot add or update a child row a foreign key constraint fails mysql' for tableA and tableC.

If i had a way to get the last_insert_id() of each inserted tableB row and use it the tableC insert statement it would resolve my issue. So i think... :-/

Comment: Are you using autoincremented tables?

Comment: yes, i'm using autoincremented primary keys in tableB and tableC, in this case.

Comment: Edited to account for autoincrement

Comment: whats happening now is that the rows i'm duplicating on tableC don't have the correct tableB ids. Each row in tableB has 1 or more rows in tableC. When i duplicate the data in tableB, the new rows in tableC all get the id from the last inserted tableB row. The result is: {idC=1, idB=1};{idC=2, idB=1};{idC=3, idB=1};{idC=4, idB=1} and it should be: {idC=1, idB=1};{idC=2, idB=1};{idC=3, idB=2};{idC=4, idB=2}.

Comment: I am not sure what is causing this.  I made a pastebin of what I did:  http://pastebin.com/JBdYV8GD

Comment: You passed in novoCodigoDoente and then hard-coded it into your select query

Comment: novoCodigoDoente is the id of the new user i'm creating. i'm creating a new user with the same data of the old user (antigoCodigoDoente). I'm i doing it wrong? Your code is working well in other tables, but since in this case i have 3 table data to duplicate something is going wrong. And its only with the last insert statement :-/